# ASP.NET Youtube Channel Regex

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation, youtube

I've seen many youtube regex here on StackOverflow and around the web but failed to find (or edit) the one I need.
What I need is to validate user input for a valid youtube url wich should also contain the Youtube page/channel.
So this is not much about Youtube direct video urls but rather to validate channels, something like:

```
https://www.youtube.com/user/myyoutubeusername
```

It would be nice if it could be used to validate even direct links to videos, youtu.be short format urls and other Youtube links by the way.

I need this in an ASP.NET regex validator control, but I guess this is secondary.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ah the many needs, but what have you *tried*?

Comment: I tried many of the regex here for example:
/^.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|\&v=)([^#\&\?]*).*/ and tried to add |user\/| in it and similar things

Answer (score 0):

Depends what characters you actually want to allow for "user" and "channel" but a quick solution could be:

```
https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?youtube\.com\/[\w-]+\/[\w-]+
```

In this case it allows for characters `[a-zA-Z_-]`. "http" protocol matches as well as "https" and "www." is optional.

Comment: I don't know which characters Youtube allows for username/channel name. I guess a-zA-Z_- should be good... I don't know if they allow for dots or other chars as well... this could be a nice simple solution for the single scope of the channel... Need to test it. Something broader would be great. For example since I don't need specific match to perform IDs extractions or such... how could I have youtube.com (or youtu.be) followed by any URL valid chars/combo ? Like a generic website regex that checks for youtube.com (youtu.be) in it?

Comment: Use or: `youtube\.com|youtu\.be`

Answer (score 0):

To get the channel name or channel id from a youtube URL use:

```
(?:https|http)\:\/\/(?:[\w]+\.)?youtube\.com\/(?:c\/|channel\/|user\/)?([a-zA-Z0-9\-]{1,})
```

This works for URL's like:

```
https://www.youtube.com/user/channelblabla
https://www.youtube.com/channel/channelblabla
https://www.youtube.com/c/channelblabla
https://www.youtube.com/channelblabla
```

If you are looking for channel id's specifically: Channel ID's start with 'UC'. I don't know of any other way to recognize channel ID's vs. channel names.